# Install Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 (SSRS) on a domain controller

Tags: sql-server

I have set up a Microsoft Windows Server 2012R2 and installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition on it. In general everything works fine. The purpose of this machine is to have a single server SharePoint 2016 Development environment. I have installed similar machines very often in the past, but never with SQL Server 2017 + SSRS.

Now i wanted to install Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services on the same machine to be able to play around with the new Reporting Services, but unfortunately i receive the following error message when executing SSRS setup:

"Installation Reporting Services on a domain controller is not supported."

Of course the message is clear! But my question is:

Is there any workaround to do this anyway, maybe with a workaround oder fix?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldnt attempt it.  Generally speaking, domain controllers should be left as completely stand-alone servers.  The risk - even if you *think* its minimal - of losing a domain controller, or even one of it's [FSMO roles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197132/active-directory-fsmo-roles-in-windows) could result in a disaster that you do not want to deal with.  In the past, I admit I have made mistakes that brought entire companies to a halt.  Believe me, thats not something you want to have to explain to your boss.

As for *why* it doesnt work, I am not 100% sure.  Without any research, my gut feeling is one of the services would conflict with the DCs core services and cause an issue.  Ive seen white papers from Microsoft that say "dont do this."  Many times Ive seen this advice ignored, as it can be done without any hacks.  However, if Microsoft *prevents* you from doing something, it is a *very* good idea to *not* do it.

Attempting to MacGyver a solution *could* work perfectly fine, but the risk is not worth the reward.  Keep your DCs free of unnecessary services, like SQL Server and SSRS.

Comment: First thanks for the advice and of course in general i would definitely agree with that 100% when would talk about an environment like production, staging or something similar. But in my case its only a development environment and playground to play around with services. In the meanwhile i have set up a second machine for the SSRS, so i wouldnt invest more time in researching of how to work around. Thank you.